# Why can't I retrieve a dynamic text value until after another value has been created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

i create table rows dynamically with jQuery and i assign each one a data id , like the code below :

```
var education_row_counter = 0;

$("#addButton").on('click', function() {
  var row = '<tr data-id="' + education_row_counter + '" >' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-id="' + education_row_counter + '" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
    '<td>' + 'arash' + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $("#eduTable").append(row);
  $("#eduTable").append('<div style="display:none"></div>');

  education_row_counter++;
});
```

however, when I want to retrieve the data-id with this command :
`$("#eduTable :nth-child(2)").data('id')` , in the console, it returns undefined, but when I click on the new and another row is added to the table, then I can't get the data-id using that same code.
can someone tell me want is the problem? please

Comment: what is the output qhen you add another row?

Comment: the first time you call `$("#myTable :nth-child(2)").data('id')` how many rows are present?

Comment: Could it be that child(2) refers to an element that does not exist until you add another ?

Comment: @Taplar and yet it logs an element the second time...

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio , the first time the table is empty . the user can add his education by clicking on the add button , wich will create a row with 3 text boxes

Comment: @ArashSedaghat Well you got it: if the table is empty, you cannot retreive tr:nth-child(2)

Comment: If there is only one tr, there also would not be a 2nd element

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio , sorry , it is the eduTable , i write it here wrong , and the first row is the header , thats why i call 2

Comment: @Taplar That's right...

Comment: @Taplar , the first table row is header , and i can get its text with the same command

Comment: So if you do nth-child(1) the first time (or any time) you get the header?

Comment: @Taplar , yes , thats why for the dynamically created one i call 2

Comment: Then please edit your question to include a runnable snippet showing the issue.  If you are indeed inserting a new row before you perform your :nth-child(2), then it should find it.

Comment: @Taplar the method suggested by charlietfl below , worked for me

Comment: @Taplar that assumes no `<thead>` or `<tbody>` as those are children also. And browsers can create a tbody where none exists in html

Comment: Fixing the issue with a different approach, doesn't help you learn what you were doing wrong with the original approach.  Edit: @charlietfl  sure, but given that the nth-child(1) returned the header row (according to the user), my assumption is there is no thead or tbody.  But I could be wrong.  Which a runnable snippet showing the issue would clear up without question.

Comment: @Taplar if I remember correctly IE always creates tbody. Haven't looked for long time though. New user here... be gentle

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just trying to get them to further demonstrate their issue.  There is a reason why trying to get the second element doesn't return anything.  If there is a thead and a tbody, the second child would be the tbody.  If they are indeed starting with a header row, and inserting a new row, then the second element would be the second row.  But they say it returns nothing.  So, if they take your answer, and forget the problem, they haven't learned what their original problem was, and the likely hood of repeating it in the future is greater than if we worked it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `last()` method or `:last` selector and target `<tr>` since there may be `<tbody>` created by browser which would be the actual child of the `<table>`

In your approach you would also have to continually adjust `nth-child(n)` as row lengths change

```
$("#eduTable tr:last").data('id')
```

Comment: Arash, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand what's expected of you when you post. "Thank you" comments aren't ideal.

Comment: Really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If it's an event on a row, can get it using target of the event and go to closest parent row. Like `$('td').click(function(){ alert( $(this).closest('tr').data('id') )})`

Answer (score 0):

i just solved this problem by writing the code like this :
`$("#eduTable tr:nth-child(n)").data('id');` , wich (n) is the number of the table row